# How can I use the `:term` command without closing the current window on exit?

Tags: neovim, terminal, normal-mode

I often use the `:term` command in my projects to create new directories or perform other work.

However, if I have multiple windows open, then executing `:term` from one of them will also close that window, when I exit the shell.

How can I execute `:term` from the current window and return back to current buffer on exit?

Comment: Note: it's about Neovim. In Vim `:term` opens new window by default.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Is it possible to “fix” Neovim?

Comment: I simply do `:new +term`

Comment: *"to create new directories"* For simple external commands, consider using `:!mkdir ...` or `:silent !mkdir ...` or `:call system('mkdir '.shellescape(...))`, etc. Use of `:term` is usually only needed when you want a full screen app, a REPL, or when you want to run a background process (long compilation) without blocking the editor. But for simple tasks and short commands there are usually better approaches than `:term`.

Comment: @filbranden, why would I want to use this longer form `:call system('mkdir '.shellescape(...))`? Isn't `!mkdir ...` almost always the faster/better alternative?

Comment: The `system()` form (better: `systemlist()`) is really useful when you want to have access to the output produced by the external command. On original Vim, `:!` will allocate a pseudo-terminal for the running process (which `system()` doesn't do) so in a way `system()` can be "simpler". Using `system()` is also typically easier to hide output or transition screens from the user. In any case, these are all simpler than `:term`, so using `:!` where possible should simplify your setup anyways!

Answer (score 2):

You can add [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5176#issuecomment-238007256) to your `init.vim`:

```
function! s:termclose() abort
  let buf = expand('#')
  if !empty(buf) && buflisted(buf) && bufnr(buf) != bufnr('%')
    execute 'autocmd BufWinLeave <buffer> split' buf
  endif
endfunction

autocmd TermClose *:$SHELL,*:\$SHELL call s:termclose()
```

(It is recommended to use a group for the auto command).

In Neovim terminal buffers are normal buffer's and when they close, `:bdelete` is executed, and `:bdelete`'s behaviour is weird if you ask me. Anyway [there are plans to definitely fix it](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5176#issuecomment-258391491)